# how to centerHorizontal textview in Android

Tags: android-studio

I use RelativeLayout, in our initial script insert android: layout_centerHorizontal = "true",
why his results are not at center position?

[image]

Comment: Post code via `code block`  and not as a linked picture.

Comment: Agreed with Geshode, but additionally, if/when you do use photos, please actually show the image using `![][url]` instead of just linking to it like `[][url]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your width in relative layout to `match_parent`. because your textview is centerhorizontal from parent/relative layout width if you using `wrap_content` the relative layout width will be as its content width.

Answer (score 0):

**What's happening** : The parent Relative layout's width is wrap_content. Since the width of the Parent equals the width of the child textview even though its center aligned it does not seem so.

**Solution** : Change the relative layout's width to 'match_parent'.

**What should happen:** The relative layout's width now spans the entire view's width and the text view should appear in the centre.
Same goes for the combination of layout_height and layout_centerVertical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="sainadh"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```